# Trying to print a list of cloudformation stacks with thier ParentId

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

This script works if i remove the `{stack['ParentId']}` but breaks when it is included.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='DevProfile')
ec2 = session.client('ec2')
regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in ec2.describe_regions()['Regions']]
print("logged in")

for region in regions:

  cloudformation = session.client('cloudformation', region_name=region)

  stacks = cloudformation.describe_stacks()

  for stack in stacks['Stacks']:
    tag_list = stack['Tags']

    for kvpair in tag_list:
      if kvpair['Key'] == "Environment":
          print(f"|| {stack['StackName']} | {stack['ParentId']} ||")
```

This is the error I get:

```
$ python stack_info.py
logged in
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\U6065745\stack_info\stack_info.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(f"|| {stack['StackName']} | {stack['ParentId']} ||")
                                       ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'ParentId'
```

According to the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation/client/describe_stacks.html) ParentId should be part of the output just like StackName.

Answer (score 0):

`ParentId` is part of the output, but only for `Nested stacks`. If you're using nested stacks, you'll see this. There's likely some stack that is a regular stack and not a nested stack, so it doesn't have this key.

For dictionaries in Python, it's better to use `get(key)` instead of brackets `[key]` to access the items. When using brackets and key does not exist, you get an exception. With `get`, you can set the default value that will be returned if the key does not exist. So, in your case, I would change the last line:

```
print(f"|| {stack.get('StackName', '')} | {stack.get('ParentId', '')} ||")
```

This will make sure that your code doesn't break if `ParentId` doesn't exist and you can later confirm that it's the stack that is not nested.